# Unicode encoding error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I have characters \u002d, \u2019, u\2022, \u25ba, \u2013 etc, coming in my data. 
I have to do `json.loads(data)`

I tried doing

```
data1 = data.encode('utf-8')
json.loads(data1)
```

I still get an error.

Also tried the below but ended up in an error

```
b1 = data.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
b2 = json.loads(b1)
```

It works if I replace the characters in my data, like '\u002d' to '-', but I do not know what other characters might creep in. So I am looking for a solution which would encode these characters

Answer (score 2):

There is **no** need to encode the data.

Feed it *directly* to `json.loads()`; the JSON standard uses `\u....` escape codes to denote unicode values **too**.

The values are not encoded in UTF-8, the Python `json` module will handle them for you.

Even if the data *was* encoded in UTF-8, the `json` module will handle that for you as well. Even if it didn't, you'd use *`str.decode()`*, not encode.

UTF-8 data looks different as well; the U+2019 codepoint looks like:

```
>>> u'\u2019'.encode('utf8')
'\xe2\x80\x99'
```

when encoded to UTF-8.

Comment: Yes it is working. But now I am not able to write it to a file. It says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\AureusBAXProject.py", line 202, in <module>  outfile.writerows(outlist)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2022' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @user1946217: Then use `io.open()` to open your output file too. Your unicode data needs to be encoded  in that case. What encoding you do that in depends on what you need to do with the output CSV.